# How can I list all form related errors in Django?

Tags: python, django

Is there a direct way of listing out all form errors in Django templates. I'd like to list out both field and non-field errors and any other form errors.

I've found out how to do this on a per-field basis but as said earlier, I'd like to list out everything.

The method I'm using doesn't seem to list out everything.

```
{% for error in form.errors %}
{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop over all the field in addition to non-field errors:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields
- Short Django snippet: [List all Form Errors](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1094/)